# Access JSON that has been serialized and encoded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a form that I gather the inputs of and save in 1 hidden text field.

In order to do this I do the following:

```
$data = JSON.stringify($('#engraving_options'));
$serializedData = JSON.stringify($('#engraving_options').serializeObject());
$encodedData = $('#textField0').val(encodeURIComponent($serializedData));
$('#textField0').val($encodedData);
```

This puts the data in [Object object] and saves that to the database as I want it to.

My question is - on the other end (PHP) how do I access that information and have it display?

There are a few spots on a site I'm working on (in Prestashop) that now show '[Object object]', and I'd like to make it nicely display the information in the object.

The current PHP for one of those display sections is this:

```
{$customization.datas.$CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD.0.value|replace:"<br />":" "|truncate:28:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

How is the best way to make that section display the information in the Object programatically?  What is the best way to dig into that Object?

Comment: `JSON.stringify($('#engraving_options'))` doesn't make sense. What is that intended to do? You are passing a jQuery object to `JSON.stringify()`. Also you can't convert the stored string `[Object object]` to anything

Comment: I'm just trying to wrap up all the inputs of a form (engraving_options) and place all those keys/values inside a text input to save to a database.  That way, later I can pull them out and display them nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want retrievable data you need to serialize all the inputs of the form.

Try

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($('#engraving_options').serializeArray());
$('#textField0').val(formData);
```

See [serializeArray() docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: How would I access that via PHP when the page loads then?  Assuming that submits and saves to the database, what's the best way to programatically pull the information out?

Comment: it will be json so you can use `json_decode()` to access as array of objects

Comment: not sure why you even need to do this if you are already submitting the form. Are you using ajax to submit?

Comment: Well this custom engraving is displayed on things like the checkout page and such.  I want it to display appropriately and there is also an area where the user will be able to edit it if need be.  So being able to pull it out and display it nicely is important.

Comment: And yes, using ajax to submit.  Submit looks like this:

Comment: var customization_entries = $('#customizationForm').serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
     async:false,
     type: 'POST',
     data: customization_entries+ '&ajax=1',
     dataType: 'json',
     url: customAction,
     success: function(data){

Comment: For some reason - it doesn't like that array in the text input unless it's been encoded - argh.